# Как средствами php в цикле сгенерировать такую таблицу:

Tags: php, mysql

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и как в этот цикл добавить заполнение из БД, но если ячейка БД пустая, то и в генерируемой таблице оставлять ячейку пустой? Пытался решить данную задачу вот таким вот образом:

```
<?
echo '<table border="1" width="300">';
    for ($i=0;$i<35;$i++) { // кол-во строк
        echo '<tr>';
            for ($j=0;$j<3;$j++) { // кол-во столбцов
                echo "<td class='zz1'>$i</td>";
            }
    }
echo '</table>';
?>
```

Но не выходит каменный цветок, совсем запутался в этих циклах. Подскажите пожалуйста найти решение. Спасибо!

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский Извините, я не пытался кого-либо оскорбить или обидеть. Спасибо, что подсказали как не выглядеть в глазах гуру "халявщиком", сейчас дополню свой вопрос тем как пытался найти решение.

Comment: что именно не выходит? все падает? пишет ошибку? выводит что-то не так? ничего не выводит?

Comment: @Grundy Мой скрипт генерирует простую таблицу в три столбца с повторяющимися ячейками, а мне нужна таблица с тем, что бы каждая ячейка таблицы была с уникальным, порядковым номером и через каждые 5 строк меняла цвет зеброй.

Comment: тег `tr` не закрыт, кстати

Comment: @Grundy Насколько мне известно теги в html языке закрывать не обязательно, это допустимые ошибки, которые исправляются бэкендом автоматически.

Comment: это да, только иногда может закрыть не совсем там где ожидалось :)

Comment: @Incognito `$a+1` и проверку на кратность не пробовали? P.s.: не стоит грубить комментаторам, давно бы ответ уже получили.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<table style="border:1px solid #ccc;width:300px;">
<?php
$t = 0;
$bg = 0;
for($i=0;$i<count($rows);$i++){ // на скрине for($i=0;$i<35;$i++){
    if($bg < 5){
        $bgr = 'fff';
    }else{
        $bgr = 'ccc';
    }
    ?>
    <tr style="background:#<?php echo $bgr; ?>;text-align:center;">
        <?php
        for($j=0;$j<3;$j++){
            $row = $rows[$i]; // здесь выводим данные из базы к примеру
            if($row->id != ''){ // если ячейка id к примеру не пустая, то:
            ?>
            <td>
                <?php echo str_repeat('0', 3 - strlen($t)) . $t; ?>
            </td>
            <?php
            }else{
                echo '<td></td>';
            }
            $t++;
        }
        ?>
    </tr>
    <?php
    $bg++;
    if($bg == 10){
        $bg = 0;
    }
}
?>
</table>
```

**Результат:**

[image: table]